# Unity3D Android plugin,: Unable to start service, intent error

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I am trying to start a service inside a Unity3d Android plugin but can not make it work. Is working on Android Studio test app, but the service call fail inside unity.

My service class

```
    public class ProximityService extends Service {
    private String TAG = "iProximity: ";

    NotificationManager _NotificationManager;
    private Context _Context;
    private static Timer _Timer = new Timer();

    public ProximityService() {
    }

    private void sendNotification() {

        Uri sound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, iRealUnityPlayerActivity.class), 0);

        builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ireal)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("message")
                .setTicker("msg: mensaje")
                .setSound(sound)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        _NotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate();

        _Context = getApplicationContext();
        _NotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    }

    // methods
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommanf()");

        //startProximity();
        sendNotification();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()");
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return null;
    }

}
```

Java class that is used to start the service:

```
public final class StatusCheckStarter {

    static Context myContext;
    // Called From C# to get the Context Instance
    public static void ReceiveContextInstance(Context tempContext) {
        myContext = tempContext;
    }
    public static String StartProximityService()
    {
        String result = "OK";

        try
        {
        myContext.startService(new Intent(myContext, ProximityService.class));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = e.getMessage();
        }

        return result;

    }

    public static String Dummy() {
        return "DONEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE";
    }

}
```

Unity C# code that is used to call the java functions to start the service:

```
    AndroidJavaClass unityClass;
    AndroidJavaObject unityActivity;
    AndroidJavaObject unityContext;
    AndroidJavaClass customClass;

    string a1 = "";
    string a2 = "";
    string a3 = "";
    string a4 = "";

    void Start () {

        //Replace with your full package name
        sendActivityReference("info.ireal.proximitylib.StatusCheckStarter");

        //Now, start service
        startService();

        Debug.Log ("START");
    }

    void sendActivityReference(string packageName)
    {
        unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        unityContext = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

        customClass = new AndroidJavaClass(packageName);
        customClass.CallStatic("ReceiveContextInstance", unityContext);
    }

    void startService()
    {
        a4 = customClass.CallStatic<string> ("Dummy"); 
        a3 = customClass.CallStatic<string>("StartProximityService");
    }
```

The Dummy method is working and return a string value, but the service does not work

Adb logcat message:

> Unable to start service Intent {
>   cmp=info.ireal.proximitytest/info.ireal.proximitylib.ProximityService
>   VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} }
>   U=0: not found

I really appreciate any help Best regards

Mariano

I am using the solution from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372910/unity3d-android-plugin-unable-to-start-service) but  still cant make it work.

EDIT

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
        android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name="info.ireal.proximitylib.ProximityService" />
        <!---<service android:name="ProximityService" />-->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the Manifest. Make sure to include the service class in the service tag.
It could be any of these problems below. Build, Run and test **each** one you try.

**1**.Add the class to the Manifest.

```
<application
    <service android:name=".ProximityService" />
</application>
```

**2**.Add the class with the full path to the Manifest.
If this does not work, use the full service class package name

```
<application
    <service android:name="info.ireal.proximitylib.ProximityService" />
</application>
```

**3**.Add the class to the Manifest from Unity itself.

Again, if that fails, go to `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Apk`

Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` from that place file to your Assets\Plugins\Android directory then include the service tag code above in the Manifest. Save and run.

**4**.Finally, use `Activity` instead of `Context`.

*Changes on the Java side*:

**A**.Rename `static Context myContext;` to `static Activity myActivity;`

**B**.Change

```
public static void ReceiveContextInstance(Context tempContext) {
    myContext = tempContext;
}
```

to

```
public static void ReceiveContextInstance(Activity tempActivity) {
    myActivity = tempActivity;
}
```

*Changes on C# side*:

**C**.Replace `customClass.CallStatic("ReceiveContextInstance", unityContext);` with `customClass.CallStatic("ReceiveContextInstance", unityActivity);`

Comment: Hi Programmer, thank you very much for your answer, i follow your tips and still get same error, i will post my AndroidManifest.xml , Im still noob in Android programming, that could be related to plugin dependency?

Comment: The library proximitylib show dependenciy on com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0, should i include this on Plugin directory?

Comment: No you shouldn't. I don't think that is the problem. I asked you a question under your question. Check that question and answer it here.

Comment: i change the java dummy method to return myActivity.toString() and the value is not null : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity@356.....

Comment: OK, seems that Im moving a little forward now, i replace the .jar with the .aar output since Unity 5 support aar libraries and the intent error gone, now have error inside the service guess that is on the notification routine cause when I comment the piece of code the error gone. Im testing all on Unity 5.3.4 , and an Android 6.0.1 device. Library build on Android Studio 2.1.2

Comment: Android 6.0.1 is different from other Android version I have worked with. The important thing that changed is the permission. Permission is now done from code. It looks like your starting service problem has been solved