# Create a native Flashlight Android Java plugin for unity 3D

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have an issue, I don't know how to access to my java plugin from Unity.

Here is the Java Code :

```
package fr.vincentmazet.utilslibrary;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;


public class FlashLight extends UnityPlayerActivity {
private CameraManager camManager;
private Context context;

public void FlashLight(Context context){
    this.camManager = (CameraManager)    context.getSystemService(context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
}

public boolean enableFlash(){
        try {
            camManager.setTorchMode("0", true);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean stopFlash(){
        try {
            camManager.setTorchMode("0", false);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

And here my c# func :

```
public bool startFlash(){
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
        using (var javaUnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass     ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {

            using (var currentActivity = javaUnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity")) {

                using (var androidPlugin = new AndroidJavaObject ("fr.vincentmazet.utilslibrary.FlashLight", currentActivity)) {

                    return androidPlugin.Call<bool> ("enableFlash");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it failed when I enter in :

```
var androidPlugin = new AndroidJavaObject  ("fr.vincentmazet.utilslibrary.FlashLight", currentActivity)
```

And I don't know how to debug, access to the stack-trace from my android.

Any ideas is appreciated thank's you by advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I don't know how to debug, access to the stack-trace from my
>   android.

Debugging your Android plugin yourself is a must. You can do this with `Debug.Log` from *Unity/C#* and `Log.V` from *Android/Java* side.

Use *Android Monitor* from *Android Studio* to view the Logs and also Exception Log from Unity.

> I don't know how to access to my java plugin from Unity

You need to [send instance of `Context`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41064329/3785314) from Unity to the Android Plugin. You also **don't** have to extend from `UnityPlayerActivity`. Totally unnecessary here.

**Permission**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

**Java:**

```
public class FlashLight{
private CameraManager camManager;
static Context myContext;

// Called From C# to get the Context Instance
public static void receiveContextInstance(Context tempContext) {
        myContext = tempContext;

 this.camManager = (CameraManager)   myContext.getSystemService(context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    }

public static boolean enableFlash(){
        try {
            camManager.setTorchMode("0", true);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean stopFlash(){
        try {
            camManager.setTorchMode("0", false);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**C#:**

```
AndroidJavaClass unityClass;
AndroidJavaObject unityActivity;
AndroidJavaObject unityContext;
AndroidJavaClass customClass;

void Start()
{
    //Replace with your full package name
    sendActivityReference("fr.vincentmazet.utilslibrary.FlashLight");

    //Enable Flashlight
    enableFlash();

   //Disable Flashlight
   //stopFlash();
}

void sendActivityReference(string packageName)
{
    unityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    unityActivity = unityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    unityContext = unityActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

    customClass = new AndroidJavaClass(packageName);
    customClass.CallStatic("receiveContextInstance", unityContext);
}

bool enableFlash()
{
   return customClass.CallStatic<bool>("enableFlash");
}

bool stopFlash()
{
   return customClass.CallStatic<bool>("stopFlash");
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works with camera  on? webcamtexture playing?