# How to toggle flashlight when using webcamtexture in unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

it seems more tricky now with new camera2 api. In the old way, you can do setFlashMode()/startPreview() and it works. But now it's using CameraManager in the android side, which is more complicated. I can toggle flashlight when no camera is used, but not when unity is using webcamtexture. Is there easy way (using AndroidJavaClass etc) to do that? If not, is there any way to do that without me writing my own WebCamTexture?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41571691/3785314)?

Comment: that one is calling setTorchMode(), which doesn't work when the camera is already on

Comment: @SunnyChow Have you got any answer for this ?