# Get Activity.Class from service in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, unity-game-engine, android-service

I'm writing Unity mobile application which uses Android native plugin. This plugin creates background location service and notifies user when he approaches specific points on map (which are architectural monuments btw).

So Service sends push notification, and when users clicks on this notification, the app should be opened from place it paused earlier.

To create this notification, I wrote next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true).build();

mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, n);
```

The trick is that Unity uses one Activity (`UnityPlayerActivity`) during app lifecycle. But I must build standalone `.jar` file with my service which cannot use `UnityPlayerActivity` class because it don't know about that.

I can get current `Activity` instance only on runtime and work with it while starting service.

**Question:** How can I get `Activity.class` from Service while creating `Intent`?

Thank you for response.

**UPD:** I cannot put my service into `Intent` constructor.  The second parameter in `Intent` constructor must be `Activity.Class` which should open when user clicks on notification. If I put `Service.Class` there, nothing opens.

So I need to put as a second parameter `UnityPlayerActivity` instance which I can get only on runtime, but don't know how to import it into service.

Comment: `Service extends Context`. Why do you need an Activity?

Comment: So you have `new Intent(this, this.getClass());`

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh, sorry, it's wrong answer. The second parameter in `Intent` constructor must be that `Activity.Class` which should open when user clicks on notification. If I put `Service.Class` there, nothing opens.

Comment: @cricket_007 So I need to put as a second parameter `UnityPlayerActivity` instance which I can get only on runtime, but don't know how to import it into service.

Comment: `Class.forName("package.name.UnityPlayerActivity")`?

Comment: @cricket_007 it throws `LinkageError` if dependency is absent. Thank you for trying help me!

Comment: This is a duplicate....Start with with [Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368762/start-android-service-from-unity3d-code/38369904#38369904) or start service with [Context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372910/unity3d-android-plugin-unable-to-start-service/38538715#38538715)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented such thing using intent `putExtra` method.

Unity side:

```
public class GPSServiceAndroidTest : MonoBehaviour {

    private AndroidJavaObject activity = null;
    private AndroidJavaObject launcher = null;

    void Start () {

        using(AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")){
            activity = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }

        using(AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.softserve.gpstest.Launcher")){
            if(pluginClass!=null){
                launcher = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                launcher.Call("startTustanService", activity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Launcher` class:

```
public class Launcher {

    private static Launcher instance;

    private Launcher() {
        Launcher.instance = this;
    }

    public static Launcher instance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Launcher();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void startTustanService(Activity currentActivity){
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(currentActivity, currentActivity.getClass());
        startServiceIntent.putExtra("notificationIntent", notificationIntent);

        currentActivity.startService(new Intent(currentActivity, TestService.class));
    }
}
```

And then get this intent in Service's `onStartCommand` method:

```
mNotificationIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra("notificationIntent");
```

Comment: I meant `public class` definition

Comment: @cricket_007 now working on Unity side representation of this code, I will update my answer when finish and notify you

Comment: @cricket_007 Extended my answer. I get `Activity` instance on Unity side and then use it when starting service in my plugin.