# Calling Android Activity from exported Unity project, NullPointerException

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have exported an Android Unity project to create and Android Studio project (as detailed here: [Exporting and running Unity3D project to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980792/exporting-and-running-unity3d-project-to-android-studio))

While, the project will now run through Android Studio, I am unable to load an Activity which I created after importing the project.

I am wondering is this possible?

I have checked other solution for NullPointerException when calling a new class in android and was unable to see any relating issues, making me question if my approach to this problem is correct

The unity project is a simlple button that will access a method in the *UnityPlayerActivity* (proved through Log), before attempting to load the new activity *AndroidTestActivity*, which just contains a TextView.

Code is as follows

Unity C#:

```
public void Click () {

    Debug.Log("Clicked");

    AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject("com.Test.AndroidTest.UnityPlayerActivity");
    jo.Call("Created");
}
```

UnityPlayerActivity.java

```
public void Created(){
    Log.e("tag", "Created");

    Intent i = new Intent(this, AndroidTestActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(i);
}
```

LogCat Output:

```
E/tag: Created
E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to 
invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4400)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4358)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4682)
         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4650)
         at com.Test.AndroidTest.UnityPlayerActivity.Created(UnityPlayerActivity.java:39)
         at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
         at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
         at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

I have also ensured that the new activity is declared in the android manifest and it has been imported in UnityPlayerActivity

Comment: you have an NPE. You have Java code. It's a dupe

Comment: See the duplicate which shows how to start activity or service. You get that error because the context/activity is null. The duplicate shows how to pass context or activity to the plugin then use that to start the service/activity

Comment: Thank you @Programmer, for anyone else reading, I solved the problem with Method 2 on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368762/start-android-service-from-unity3d-code